# How do you subtract Double.pi and Float.pi in Swift?

Tags: swift, floating-point, double, pi

I want to do `Double.pi - Float.pi`, but I am getting an error:

> Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Float.

When I typecast `Float` to `Double` or `Double` to `Float` (for example: `Double(Float.pi))`, the result is wrong. How can I subtract them?

```
let floatPi = Float.pi
let Pi = Double.pi
print("float pi = \(floatPi)")
print("double pi = \(Pi)")
let substraction = Pi - floatPi
print(substraction)
```

Here is the result from the above:

> float pi =  3.1415925

> double pi = 3.141592653589793

> error: MyPlayground.playground:20:23: error: binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Float'
> let substraction = Pi - floatPi

When I try this:

```
let floatPi = Double(Float.pi)
```

The result is:

> float pi =  3.141592502593994

> double pi = 3.141592653589793

> 1.5099579897537296e-07

Comment: How is the result wrong? What do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: I expect the result of this phrase 3.141592653589793 - 3.1415925

Comment: I voted to reopen. Per [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/1845969-pi), `Float.pi` and `Double.pi` are rounded toward zero. So `Float.pi` differs from `Double.pi` and also from `Float(Double.pi)`, which rounds to nearest in the conversion from `Double` to `Float`.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @LeoDabus: This should not be marked as a duplicate of that because this one involves an unusual rounding choice. Please do not promiscuously mark floating-point questions as duplicates of that one, because it prevents explaining specific issues in floating-point.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the issue is that OP is using Float32 instead of Float64.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is more clear now.

Comment: @LeoDabus: **An** issue is that the OP is subtracting an IEEE-754 binary32 value from a binary64 value. **Another** issue is, as I wrote, that there is an unusual rounding method in use. Please do not promiscuously mark floating-point questions as duplicates of that one, because it prevents explaining specific issues in floating-point.

Comment: I did not mark anything as duplicate I just commented that it was a possible duplicate of that question so that OP could read those answers as well

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That is interesting, I never noticed that before. The corresponding source code is here https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointTypes.swift.gyb#L454 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing a difference is that `Double` can represent the value of π more accurately, because it uses more bits to get more precision. Both `Float.pi` and `Double.pi` are created by representing the mathematical value of π as accurately as possible in the `Float` or `Double` type without exceeding the mathematical value (the value of π is rounded to the nearest representable value in the direction of zero). So `Float.pi` and `Double.pi` have different values, and subtracting them produces about 1.5•10<sup>−7</sup>.

Further, the decimal numerals you see when you print `Float.pi` or `Double.pi` with default formatting are not the actual values inside the computer. Both `Float` and `Double` use a binary format in which each number is represented as a significand (in effect, some integer) multiplied by a negative power of two (including negative powers of 2, such as 2<sup>−34</sup>, for example). So the actual value of `Float.pi` is 3.141592502593994140625, and the actual value of `Double.pi` is 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875.